# Order Multiple Arrays (Including Each Other)

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

Let's say we have arrays like below.

```
$arr00 = [0,1,2,...,9]; // It includes 9 arrays. So the score should be 9.
$arr01 = [0,1,...,8];   // score = 8
...
$arr09 = [0];           // score = 0
```

**ArrScore** (definition): If an array include an array with all elements it
   gets one point. So in this case $arr00's total score is 9. Because it
   includes all other 9 arrays. And $arr09's score will be 0.

**Actual Conditions**

- Our array elements could be random numbers. (not sequent orders ascending +1)
- There could be thousands of arrays.
- Our arrays are always flat. (no duplicated element in an array)
- We are using php (any theoretical approach is also ok)
- Think that you have a standard PC and you will order these arrays everyday once. (No need for the result of "which arr eats which ones". Just ArrScores.)

**Goal** is to order arrays by **ArrScore**. And we need ArrScores. What should be the approach? (Theoretical or practical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, this might help:

```
function compare($a,$b) {
   if(count(array_intersect($a, $b)) == count($a)) return -1;
   else return 1;
}
$arr0 = [0,2,4,7];
$arr1 = [7,0,2,9,4];
$arr2 = [4,2];

$arr = [$arr0,$arr1,$arr2];

usort($arr,"compare");

foreach($arr as $a) {
   print_r($a);
}
```

prints:

Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 0 [2] => 2 [3] => 9 [4] => 4 )

EDIT:
Compute the ArrayScore for each array:

```
$arr0 = [0,2,4,7];
$arr1 = [7,0,2,9,4];
$arr2 = [4,2];

$arr = [$arr0,$arr1,$arr2];
$arrayScores = [];
//initialize the Scores with 0
foreach($arr as $a){
   $arrayScores[] = 0;
}
//run through all arrays
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
//with $j=$i+1, every combination is only checked once
   for($j=$i+1; $j<count($arr);$j++){
      if(count(array_intersect($arr[$j], $arr[$i])) == count($arr[$j])) {
         $arrayScores[$i]++;
      }
      if(count(array_intersect($arr[$i], $arr[$j])) == count($arr[$i])){
         $arrayScores[$j]++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @pBuch . I tried it to work with your compare function but I could not achieve. I need the scores for every array.

Comment: Please describe it one again for me. As of my example (if that is a valid one), what is the wanted result? Do you want to order the arrays one by one? Or do you want to include the Score in the output?

Comment: I need all array's scores. I do not need "which arrays include which ones". An array's score is equal to the number of arrays which are included by it.

Comment: See my edit for computing the arrayScore for each array. This code is untested. Hope this fits you better.

Comment: Yes it works! It is the best candidate for my core. After modifying it for my extra needs and trying it for thousands of arrays, I will share the results with you.